# Tracking with find my iphone

Tags: icloud, find-my-iphone

Can I see on "find my iphone" a sort of tracking of where my iphone has been for a day? For exampel Between 1 and 5 pm my iphone were on this addresses..etc

Answer (score 1):

it does not show history but if the device is shut off or location services disabled, find my iPhone will show the last known location of your device

Answer (score 0):

No - Apple's Find My iPhone lists only one data point for each device.

It doesn't show history so you'd need to record location periodically and store the results elsewhere to do that.